# Regular expression for DN addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression in javascript that must follow the conditions

1. All segment in the DN address should follow the sequence `cn=<name>,ou=<name>,o=<bic8>,o=swift`
2. All segments should be separated with `,`.
3. The DN address should have maximum of 100 characters.
4. No space is allowed.
5. Minimum of 2 and maximum of 10 segments are allowed in a DN address.
6. The `<name>` part must contain minimum of 2 characters and maximum 20 alphanumeric characters. The characters should be in lower case. Only one special character is allowed to be used i.e. `-`(Hypen).
7. The DN address will have maximum 2 numbers. The `<name>` part can contain maximum of 2 numerical digits.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider of parsing that yourself instead of invoking a regex.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to state what problem you are having while trying to write a regular expression that does this?

Comment: how to validate the comma separed text and in regexp how to validate minimum length and maximum length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested code follows, don't blame me if it blows up your computer:

```
var parseDn(str)
  var m = /^cn=(.*?),ou=(.*?),o=(.*?),o=swift$/.exec(str);
  if (!m) { return null; } // (a) and (b).
  if (s.length > 100) { return null; } // (c).
  if (/\s/.exec(s)) { return null; } // (d).
  var x = {cn:m[1], ou:m[2], o:m[3]};
  var isValidName = function(s) { return (/^[a-z-]{2,20}$/).exec(s); }
  if (!isValidName(x.cn) || !isValidName(x.ou) || !isValidName(x.o)) {
    return null; // (f).
  }
  var countNumbers = function(s) { return s.replace(/\D/g, "").length; }
  if (countNumbers(x.cn)>2 || countNumbers(x.ou)>2 || countNumbers(x.o)>2) {
    return null; // (g).
  }
  return x; // => {"cn":"name", "ou":"name", "o":"bic8"}
}
```

Note that (e) and a few of the points regarding "segments" are completely unchecked since the description is vague.  But this should get you started...

Comment: Hii, In X.cn its taking only one value is theer any other one so that it will take all the cn values if enter more than one

Answer (score 2):

I think `.split()` is a lot easier to use in this case.

First split the entire string on the `,`'s and then split every separate segment of the resulting array on the `=`'s.

Especially on a well defined spec as this, split is more then enough to handle it.